# Mesh / divide / explode values in a column of a DataFrames according to a number of meshes for each value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a DataFrame

df1 :

```
        value   mesh

0       10      2
1       12      3
2       5       2
```

obtain a new DataFrame *df2* in which for each value of *df1* there are `mesh` values, each one obtained by dividing the corresponding value of *df1* by its `mesh`:

df2 :

```
    value/mesh
0   5
1   5
2   4
3   4
4   4
5   2.5
6   2.5
```

More general:

df1 :

```
    value   mesh_value  other_value 
0   10      2           0
1   12      3           1
2   5       2           2
```

obtain:

df2 :

```
    value/mesh_value    other_value
0   5                   0
1   5                   0
2   4                   1
3   4                   1
4   4                   1
5   2.5                 2
6   2.5                 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `map`

```
df2['new'] = df2['value/mesh'].map(dict(zip(df1.eval('value/mesh'),df1.index)))
Out[243]: 
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    2
6    2
Name: value/mesh, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows:

- Use [`Series.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) for `value / mesh_value`, and apply [`Series.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) using [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with `df.mesh_value` as the input array for the `repeats` parameter.
- Next, use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to combine the result with `df.other_value` along `axis=1`.
- Finally, rename the column with result of `value / mesh_value` (its default name will be `0`) using [`df.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html), and chain [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to reset to a standard index.

```
df2 = pd.concat([df.value.div(df.mesh_value).reindex(
    np.repeat(df.index,df.mesh_value)),df.other_value], axis=1)\
    .rename(columns={0:'value_mesh_value'}).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df2)

   value_mesh_value  other_value
0               5.0            0
1               5.0            0
2               4.0            1
3               4.0            1
4               4.0            1
5               2.5            2
6               2.5            2
```

Or slightly different:

- Use [`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to add a column with the result of `df.value.div(df.mesh_value)`, and reindex / rename in same way as above.
- Use [`df.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) to get rid of columns that you don't want (`value`, `mesh_value`) and use [`df.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to change the column order (e.g. we want `['value_mesh_value','other_value']` instead of other way around (hence: `[1,0]`). And again, reset index.
- We put all of this between brackets and assign it to `df2`.

```
df2 = (df.assign(tmp=df.value.div(df.mesh_value)).reindex(
    np.repeat(df.index,df.mesh_value))\
    .rename(columns={'tmp':'value_mesh_value'})\
        .drop(columns=['value','mesh_value']).iloc[:,[1,0]]\
            .reset_index(drop=True))

# same result
```